# Rounding to two decimal places in Android

Tags: android, math, decimal

Should be simple I know but I cant find an answer anywhere. I'm trying to round up to two decimal places, so if my answer is 164.9835 I'd like the answer to be displayed as 164.99. But what I have so far is rounding it to 164.98 for some reason.

Any help much appreciated.

```
            double number1 = Double.parseDouble(num1.getText().toString());
            double number2 = Double.parseDouble(num2.getText().toString());
            double number3 = Double.parseDouble(num3.getText().toString());
            double number4 = Double.parseDouble(num4.getText().toString());
            double sum = (((number1 * number2)/1000)*0.5)*(number3 - number4);
            total.setText (String.format("£%s", new java.text.DecimalFormat("##.##").format(sum)));
```

Comment: Why would that round to 164.99?

Comment: Typical approaches to rounding would say that `164.9835` rounds down to `164.98`, not up to `164.99`. Are you sure that you want `164.980000000000000001` to become `164.99`?

Comment: Yeah I'm afraid i do need it to round up, even at 164.980000000001, it needs to be 164.99. It's to provide a bit of a legal safety net I suppose for what I'm doing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to round up you can use this method

**cantDecimal = 2;
number = 164.9835**

```
public static double aroundUp(double number, int canDecimal) {
    int cifras = (int) Math.pow(10, canDecimal);
    return Math.ceil(number * cifras) / cifras;
}
```

**return = 164.99**

Extra: Ceil Method in Math.
The method ceil gives the smallest integer that is greater than or equal to the argument.

Comment: Mathematically, this works, but I worry about the imprecision of floating-point math breaking your algorithm in some places. I would consider skipping the division and hacking in the decimal separator using string manipulation.

Comment: Thanks, but a proper noob question now...Where does this go/how do I apply this to my code above? Thanks

Comment: you need copy this method and call: total.setText (String.format("£%s", aroundUp(sum,2)));
do not forget to vote the answer :)